# Time steps and convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I was wondering if someone could please give me an explanation why we look at larger and larger time steps in order to see if we have convergence. I have played around with matlab and noticed when I use more Monte Carlo Simulations the errors are closer in value over different time steps. I have and still am checking different resources please help :)

Thanks in advance!!

More details on the situation: I am simulating a stock price using the Black-Scholes SDE. My Matlab code is below.

```
%EMWEAK  Test weak convergence of Euler-Maruyama
%
% Solves    dX = lambda*X dt + mu*X dW,   X(0) = Xzero,
%        where lambda = 2, mu = 0.1 and Xzer0 = 1.
%
% E-M uses 5 different timesteps: 2^(p-10),  p = 1,2,3,4,5.
% Examine weak convergence at T=1:   | E (X_L) - E (X(T)) |.
%
% Different paths are used for each E-M timestep.
% Code is vectorized over paths.
%
% Uncommenting the line indicated below gives the weak E-M method.

mu = 0.05; sigma = 0.25; Xzero = 50; T = 1;  % problem parameters
M = 4000;                               % number of paths sampled

Xem = zeros(5,1);                        % preallocate arrays
for p = 1:5                              % take various Euler timesteps
       Dt = 1^(p-5); L = T/Dt;          % L Euler steps of size Dt 
       Xtemp = Xzero*ones(M,1);            
       for j = 1:L
           Winc = sqrt(Dt)*sign(randn(M,1)); %% use for weak E-M %%
           Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*mu*Xtemp + sigma*Xtemp.*Winc;
       end
       Xem(p) = mean(Xtemp);
end
Xerr = abs(Xem - Xzero*exp(mu));

Dtvals = 2.^([1:5]-10);          
loglog(Dtvals,Xerr,'g*-'), hold on
loglog(Dtvals,Dtvals,'r--'),    % reference slope of 1
axis([1e-3 1e-1 1e-4 1])
xlabel('\Delta t'), ylabel('| E(X(T)) - Sample average of X_L |')
title('emweak.m','FontSize',10)

mu = 0.05; sigma = 0.25; Xzero = 50; T = 1;  % problem parameters
M = 40000;
Xem = zeros(5,1);                        % preallocate arrays
for p = 1:5                              % take various Euler timesteps
       Dt = 1^(p-5); L = T/Dt;          % L Euler steps of size Dt 
       Xtemp = Xzero*ones(M,1);            
       for j = 1:L
           Winc = sqrt(Dt)*sign(randn(M,1)); %% use for weak E-M %%
           Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*mu*Xtemp + sigma*Xtemp.*Winc;
       end
       Xem(p) = mean(Xtemp);
end
Xerr = abs(Xem - Xzero*exp(mu));

Dtvals = 2.^([1:5]-10);          
loglog(Dtvals,Xerr,'black*-')

mu = 0.05; sigma = 0.25; Xzero = 50; T = 1;  % problem parameters
M = 4000000;
Xem = zeros(5,1);                        % preallocate arrays
for p = 1:5                              % take various Euler timesteps
       Dt = 1^(p-5); L = T/Dt;          % L Euler steps of size Dt 
       Xtemp = Xzero*ones(M,1);            
       for j = 1:L
           Winc = sqrt(Dt)*sign(randn(M,1)); %% use for weak E-M %%
           Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*mu*Xtemp + sigma*Xtemp.*Winc;
       end
       Xem(p) = mean(Xtemp);
end
Xerr = abs(Xem - Xzero*exp(mu));

Dtvals = 2.^([1:5]-10);          
loglog(Dtvals,Xerr,'b*-')

mu = 0.05; sigma = 0.25; Xzero = 50; T = 1;  % problem parameters
M = 10000000;
Xem = zeros(5,1);                        % preallocate arrays
for p = 1:5                              % take various Euler timesteps
       Dt = 1^(p-5); L = T/Dt;          % L Euler steps of size Dt 
       Xtemp = Xzero*ones(M,1);            
       for j = 1:L
           Winc = sqrt(Dt)*sign(randn(M,1)); %% use for weak E-M %%
           Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*mu*Xtemp + sigma*Xtemp.*Winc;
       end
       Xem(p) = mean(Xtemp);
end
Xerr = abs(Xem - Xzero*exp(mu));

Dtvals = 2.^([1:5]-10);          
loglog(Dtvals,Xerr,'y*-'),hold off
```

Comment: I think you should give more details on the situation you are considering. Monte Carlo alone is a bit vague.

Comment: I will add as many details as I can Im currently doing a project and am a little lost. If you have any more questions I will do my best to ask.